# How to use omniauth to authenticate users from a custom Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm currently working on a rails Spree application(v 1.3.x).

I have also another application that i have created couple of months ago just suppose **myfirstapp.com** that is live and so many users have created account on this application so they are registered users now.

**So, now i want in my new application which is one i'm currently working on just suppose it is **mysecondapp.com** to allow registered users  (i.e users who created account on myfirstapp.com) to sign_in in my second app without using my **secondapp** signup proccess. They should authenticate from myfirstapp.com and get into my secondapp.**

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There is beautiful railscast for this http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth?view=comments

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use your first app authentication on the seconde one, you can create a link just like facebook or twitter with redirects to a controller and then this controller sends a request to your first app(you will need the security code to do that) and then get the response, save the data you want(user_id or account) and works great...

Api class using [protect_from_forgery](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html):

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery :except => 'custom_login'
end
```

Doing this you will avoid the default rails protection, with verifies the

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
```

commonly used on rails forms.
Then you can implement your secret hash code, and verifies it like:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery :except => :login_from_app2

def login_from_app2
    if params[:authentication] == auth_hash
        if login(params[:user_credentials])
            render :text => "Success" #better you return a json
        else
            render :text => "Fail login" #better you return a json
        end
    else
        render :text => 'Invalid security hash'
    end
end


def auth_hash
    "8f2e4b354f193744272fe246ca9e8bf5"
end

end
```

That way you have a code with only app2 will send on a "post" request to access app1
and you can control the login.

I dont know if this is 100% secure, i think it is, but i will be glad if anyone could explain why this is not a good approach in this case.

Comment: Thanks Vinicius. I will definitely try this.

Comment: I know this is not "omniauth" but omniauth is made to work with the authentication process of twitter and facebook, and so on, wich have a personal mechanism of doing the authentication process, to use a gem first u need to have your own authentication system and implement that on your "personal omniauth"